how to fix django CSRF error for admin area?
I set up docker-compose to server django v5.0.6 and I see login page but after signin I face with CSRF error.
my docker-compose containers:

Nginx
web (django container)
postgres

all the configs are correct and I can call APIs and see login page of admin area.
nginx.conf
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        }
        location /static {
                autoindex on;
                alias /static;
        }
}

.env
...
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=example.com,web
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=["example.com"]
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['example.com']
...

how can I fix it?
I try to setup based on the configs but I gave 403 error only for admin area. all APIs works fine.
